# cross table with dynamic results

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table, plpgsql

I have a crosstab written in postgresql, and I want to return the values ​​of "company_name" dynamically, Query:

```html
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
    'SELECT
        e.nome_empresa,
        f.nome_fornecedor ,
        ic.valor_unitario
    FROM empresa e
    INNER JOIN fornecedor_empresa   AS fe   ON e.id_empresa =       fe.id_empresa
    INNER JOIN fornecedor           AS f    ON f.id_fornecedor =    fe.id_fornecedor
    INNER JOIN cotacao              AS c    ON c.id_empresa =       e.id_empresa
    INNER JOIN item_cotacao         AS ic   ON ic.id_cotacao =      c.id_cotacao
    WHERE fe.registro_ativo = true
    ORDER BY 1, 2'
) AS (
    nome_empresa        VARCHAR(255),
    nome_fornecedor1    NUMERIC(15,5),
    nome_fornecedor2    NUMERIC(15,5),
    nome_fornecedor3    NUMERIC(15,5)
);
```

in all the examples I've seen, the second croostab parameter always needs to be entered manually
I have a huge list of "supplier_name" and I didn't want to type these names manually, I want to pull the supplier_name dynamically from my supplier table..
how can i do this? it's possible ?

Comment: It's not possible. SQL is not good at formatting results. Your best option (imho) is just let SQL return a normal result and do the pivot operation in your app presentation manager.